# How to control the visibility of a popup menu programmatically?

Tags: eclipse, popup, visibility

I'm extending Eclipse using the Eclipse plugin infrastructure, and I've come into a problem:

I would like to control the visibility of a popup menu depending on the value of an preference variable. So, I must control it programmatically or by adding an parameter in the plugin.xml.

Please help me.

Best regards.
Imen.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenu`, you cannot directly control the state, as Eclipse may show the item as enabled until you try to use it -- only then will your plugin get enabled, and evaluate its visibility. A better way is to use the [`org.eclipse.ui.menus`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_cmd_menus.htm) extension, which has finer control (but also more overhead in terms of what you need to configure):

> Contribution visibility
>
> A command's
>   enabled state is controlled by a
>   combination of the command is handled
>   and if so, the handler's enabled
>   state. Menu contributions can use core
>   expressions to control the command's
>   visibility in menus and toolbars.